# FQL Post Insights returns nothing

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I'm trying to figure out why a simple FQL query to get post insights is failing.  I have manage_pages and read_insights permissions, and facebook won't give me any hints as to what I'm doing wrong:

```
    $query1 = "SELECT post_id, message, created_time, attachment FROM stream WHERE actor_id='XXXXXXXX' and source_id='XXXXXXXXX' order by created_time";
    $query2 = "SELECT object_id, metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #query1) AND metric = 'post_impressions_unique' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-11-28') AND period=period('lifetime')";
    $queries = '{
    "query1": "' . $query1 . '",
    "query2": "' . $query2 . '"
    }';
    $data = $facebook->api_client->fql_multiquery($queries);
```

When I look at `$data`, I see many posts for the results of `$query1`, and I see nothing for the results of `$query2`.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone help?

Thanks!

DW

Comment: I've also tried doing the query in two different steps, just in case it was a problem with fql_multiquery().  I run the first query by itself using fql_query() and then I take the results to the second query, and I still get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug running queries on "stream" from a fql.multiquery, i have reported it. try the queries as single queries to test: fql.query